# Issue to SaveAs a word document in UFT using VB

Tags: vb6, qtp, hp-uft

Made a function to save a word document previously created and modified in another function, but it is sending me an error: **This is not a valid file name.**
    This is my code:

```
Set obj_Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
obj_Word.Visible = True
Set doc = obj_Word.Documents.Open("C:\Evidencias3.docx")
NombreDocumento = DataTable.Value("Preguntas","Global")

Sub SaveEvidences()
obj_Word.Visible = True
    doc.SaveAs("C:\Evidencias_"& NombreDocumento &".docx")
    obj_Word.Quit
    Set obj_Word = Nothing
End Sub
```

I appreciated any help or recommended

Comment: what's the string value you get from NombreDocumento?

Comment: Why is this tagged VB6?  Doesn't this product use VBScript as its macro scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean out the file name before saving:

```
Public Function CleanFileName(ByVal sIn As String) As String
    Dim sOut As String, sIllegalChars As String
    sIllegalChars = "\/:*|?<>" + Chr(34)
    sOut = sIn
    For q = 1 To Len(sIllegalChars)
        sOut = Replace(sOut, Mid(sIllegalChars, q, 1), "_")
    Next
    CleanFileName = sOut
End Function
```

Usage:

```
doc.SaveAs(CleanFileName("C:\Evidencias_"& NombreDocumento &".docx"))
```

Reference: [MSDN - Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @ArmandoZaldivar: glad this helped You, please consider to mark the answer as accepted so other people can find it useful as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is in the line:

```
NombreDocumento = DataTable.Value("Preguntas","Global")
```

Not familiar with the code, is it possible that it is returning a null value?  If so, you could try to append an empty string to it:

```
NombreDocumento = DataTable.Value("Preguntas","Global") & ""
```

Either way, I would debug the code and see what the constructed filename actually is.  Perhaps then it will become obvious.